# Kendo JS: Call setOptions on a grid without triggering a reload of the data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with the KendoJS grid controller. Essentially I am trying to resize the grid on resizing the window to keep it filling the available space effectively.

I've found [setOptions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions) to change properties of the grid, and created this function to resize:

```
setHeight: function() {
  var header_height = $('#local_toolbar').height();
  header_height += $('#local_toolbar').next().height();
  $('[data-role="querygrid"]').data('kendoGrid').setOptions(height: `${header_height}px`);
}
```

This does work correctly, but it also triggers a reload of the data store, which I don't want for two reasons:

- It can sometimes take a second or two
- The data is unlikely to have changed in the meantime, so it's unnecessary.

Is there a way to set the height of a Kendo grid without triggering this reload?